# Obtain $\{h_1,h_2,\ldots\}$ from $\{f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots\}$ with $f(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(-h_i s)h_i$

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-transforms

I need to obtain $\{h_1,h_2,\ldots\}$ when given $\{f(0),f(1),f(2),\ldots\}$ with $f$ defined as follows
$$f(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(-h_i s)h_i$$

We know that $h_i>0$. Is there a way to do this numerically in Mathematica? (perhaps by viewing this sum as approximation to Laplace transform?)

As a realistic example, take $h_i=i^{-p}$ with $p>1$, so we can produce $\{h_i\}$ and $\{f(s)\}_s$ for testing. I'd be  very curious to see if the `backward` method can be fixed in the snippet below to produce correct values. (without relying on knowledge that $h_i=i^{-p}$)

```
p = 2;
n = 10;
hi = Table[i^-p, {i, 1, n}];
forward[s_] := Total@Table[Exp[-h*s] h, {h, hi}];
fi = Table[forward[s], {s, 0, 20}]; (* 20 is arbitrary,can use more *)
backward[fi_] := ConstantArray[1, n];
Print["Error: ", N@Norm[hi - backward[fi]]] (* Error:2.82533,but want small *)
```

**background** this would let one get get spectrum of the Hessian just by knowing the sequence of loss values seen during gradient descent (mathoverflow [post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396959/inverse-of-moment-generating-function-in-terms-of-moments)).

Comment: There is no definition of: `fixnan` ?

Comment: I suspect the problem is ill posed in some limits. Consider $h_i\rightarrow 0$. Then, we can expand the exponent $f(s)=m_1+m_2 s$, with $m_n=\sum_i h_i^n$. This can be matched by just $h_{1,2}\neq0$ and might be quite different from the original values.

Comment: I'd suggest you cross-post at the [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com) to get high-level answers using fancy tricks instead of attempts to optimize the numerics. As @yarchik points out, this may be an ill-posed problem that requires skillful math.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk doh, rookie mistake, fixed.

Comment: @Roman: good idea, posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196166/obtaining-h-i-by-evaluating-fs-sum-i-1n-exp-h-i-sh-i

Answer (score 3):

`FindMinimum` seems able to handle this. I had to increase precision to deal with machine underflow in intermediate steps. I gave decreasing initial values mostly to avoid issues from the fact that all permutations of solutions are solutions.

```
p = 2;
n = 10;
hi = Table[i^-p, {i, 1, n}];
forward[s_] := Total@Table[Exp[-h*s] h, {h, hi}];
fi = Table[forward[s], {s, 0, 20}];
nfi = N@fi

(* Out[146]= {1.54977, 0.843641, 0.550879, 0.416048, 0.343991, 0.298764, \
0.266406, 0.241201, 0.220584, 0.203246, 0.188417, 0.17558, 0.164363, \
0.154479, 0.145704, 0.137859, 0.130799, 0.124408, 0.11859, 0.113267, \
0.108375} *)

ReverseSort[
 Array[h, 10] /. 
  FindMinimum[Total[(tab - SetPrecision[nfi, 35])^2], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{h[j], 1/j}, {j, n}]], 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30][[2]]]

During evaluation of In[174]:= FindMinimum::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
(* Out[174]= {0.999999682217788515057820501879, \
0.250007532874453058352102142461, 0.111001958762796311103481195191, \
0.0630424051228392656581485771755, 0.0391881858660591314439462684730, \
0.0275113247683531983283965925770, 0.0208627627590327107070036459028, \
0.0164120998273065347430017461150, 0.0122706341492709874991867790213, \
0.00947113971924063203573798379684} *)
```

For comparison:

```
In[188]:= N[hi]

(* Out[188]= {1., 0.25, 0.111111, 0.0625, 0.04, 0.0277778, 0.0204082, 0.015625, 0.0123457, 0.01} *)
```

One could use `NArgMin` similarly, with small changes to the syntax. Unfortunately it seems to be quite slow at bignum precision.

Comment: Just to compare. The command of Maple `restart;
with(DirectSearch);
[BoundedObjective, CompromiseProgramming, DataFit, 

  ExponentialWeightedSum, GlobalOptima, GlobalSearch, Minimax, 

  ModifiedTchebycheff, Search, SolveEquations, WeightedProduct, 

  WeightedSum]


n := 20;
h := [seq(1/i^2, i = 1 .. n)];
x := [seq(x || i, i = 1 .. n)];
f := unapply(exp(-s*t)/t, s, t);
 f := proc (s, t) options operator, arrow; exp(-t*s)/t end proc

SolveEquations([seq(f(j, x[j]) = f(j, h[j]), j = 1 .. n)], {seq(0 <= x || i, i = 1 .. n)}, evaluationlimit = 500000, tolerances = 10^(-8));
`

Comment: performs  $[x1 = 0.991539612099505, x10 = 0.00999891156588917, x11 = 0.00826401762827066,   x12 = 0.00694467136007010, x13 = 0.00591704194477822, x14 = 0.00510239116647066, x15 = 0.00444439932605931, x16 = 0.00390626775242310, x17 = 0.00346013991841357, x18 = 0.00308644313524224, x19 = 0.00277006254538837, x2 = 0.249022584946174, x20 = 0.00250002020816142, x3 = 0.110867179220868, x4 = 0.0624202126091230, x5 = 0.0400234277954353, x6 = 0.0278010812054897, x7 = 0.0204136309055576, x8 = 0.0156324412762755, x9 = 0.0123460851848005]
 .$

Comment: And for `n := 10;
h := [seq(1/i^3, i = 1 .. n)]:` results in `[x1 = 1.00000001942543, x10 = 0.00100000000000192, x2 = 0.124999999969911, x3 = 0.0370370370381836, x4 = 0.0156250000026319, x5 = 0.00799999999991006, x6 = 0.00462962962985258, x7 = 0.00291545189517407, x8 = 0.00195312499998240, x9 = 0.00137174211248244]`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so my answer is not a full answer but its a step in the right direction.

We can't possibly solve the system and NSolve seems to hang around and not go towards a solution so we have to take the route of numerical optimizations.

Initially, we set the equations to solve for:

```
fs[s_]:=Sum[Exp[-h[i]*s]*h[i],{i,1,n}]
equs=(N[fi[[#+1]]]-fs[#])&/@Range[0,n-1];
```

Now, we start off by a quick NelderMead-Method based optimization of the total absolute value of all equations. This wont give us a solution, but will bring us near it to provide nice starting values:

```
initialPreGuesses=Last[NMinimize[{Total[Abs[equs]],Table[h[i]>0,{i,1,n}]},Table[h[i],{i,1,n}],Method->"NelderMead"]]
```

We can now refine this solution again by the use off FindMinimum and our current solution as starting point. It will complain that it didn't find the optimal minimum but this is due to insufficient amount of steps. This line will take quite a few seconds to calculate. You can improve this approximation by increasing the MaxIterations-option. (It could maybe find the solution but it would take a long time I guess)

```
initialGuesses=Last@FindMinimum[{Total[Abs[equs]],And@@Table[h[i]>0,{i,1,n}]},Table[{h[i],h[i]/.initialPreGuesses},{i,1,n}],MaxIterations->10^4]
```

To finish this off to a nice approximated solution, we employ FindRoot to try to find the roots to our equation directly. As a method we choose the Newton method with an acompanied "TrustRegion" step size control with finely tuned parameters:

```
solution=Reverse[Sort[FindRoot[equs,Table[{h[i],h[i]/.initialGuesses},{i,1,n}],MaxIterations->10^6,Method->{"Newton", "StepControl" -> {"TrustRegion","MaxScaledStepSize"->10^-6,"AcceptableStepRatio"->10^-5,"StartingScaledStepSize"->10^-6}}][[All,2]]]]
```

All this setup takes around 20s for $n=10$ to deliver a solution with the accuracy of:

```
Norm[hi - solution]
```

> 0.00391442

Not quite perfect but as I said: increasing the amount of steps in the FindMinimum will improve the inital starting points and thus better solutions while increasing calculation times.